# Angular and Angular UI Bootstrap - Submit a form on Enter key

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am following form submission guidelines in the [AngularJS documentation](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0/docs/api/ng/directive/form#submitting-a-form-and-preventing-the-default-action), however the form is not being submitted when I hit the Enter key. What do I need to do make this work? Here's my code. The important bit is that I am using `ng-click` to specify a handler for the submit button:

(**Edit 1**: Code below edited based on @Pavel Horal's suggestion. Buttons have been moved into the form. Still no luck.)

(**Edit 2**: This code actually works. You have to be in an input field when you press enter. This solves the issue.)

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <form>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="payee">Payee</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="payee" placeholder="Enter payee"
                    ng-model="vm.txn.payee" required>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="memo">Memo</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="memo" placeholder="Enter memo"
                   ng-model="vm.txn.memo">
        </div>

        ...

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" ng-click="vm.ok()">OK</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="vm.cancel()">Cancel</button>
    </form>
</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
</div>
```

Comment: Your submit button is outside of the `<form>` element. Submit via *Enter* key is a feature of a browser, not Angular's. When hitting *Enter* the browser finds first `<input type="submit">`, `<input type="image">` or `<button type="submit">` and submits the form while *activating* that control .

Comment: Added my comment as a proper answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your submit button is outside of the `<form>` element. Submit via *Enter key* is a browser feature, not a feature of AngularJS.

When hitting *Enter* the browser tries to find finds first submit button and submits the form by emulating `click` event on it. When the submit button is outside of your `<form>`, browser will do nothing.

For more information you can check the [specification of *implicit submission*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#implicit-submission).

Comment: Thanks @Pavel. Code edited based on your suggestion. Still no luck. I think it has something to do with Angular UI Bootstrap. I don't see a good form example in their docs.

Comment: Maybe... it works without it (http://plnkr.co/edit/rRoKz9FJikLOi7K7ZjoV?p=preview) .

Comment: @Naresh works with UI Bootstrap as well - http://plnkr.co/edit/rRoKz9FJikLOi7K7ZjoV?p=preview .

Comment: As soon as you add a second input field, the Enter key stops working. This is as documented by the AngularJS Docs in my original question.

Comment: Add `type="button"` to the other button - http://plnkr.co/edit/wds7t6eiy2RdnOzgjiWn?p=preview. Submit is the default type - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-type .

Comment: The issue comes in with a second input field, not with a second button. See this: http://plnkr.co/edit/OpMsO7DioJveYEgyXrNC?p=preview

Comment: That still works for me (tested in Chrome and FFox).

Comment: Hmmm. Surprised. Not working for me on Chrome, Firefox or Safari! I am on a Mac.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79345/discussion-between-pavel-horal-and-naresh).

Comment: I figured it out. I was hitting enter when no input field had focus (when the dialog box came up). Form submission can happen only when an input field has focus.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply achieve by adding `ng-submit` directive on the form level. That will get call on the enter of any of the form level field.

**Markup**

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <form ng-submit="vm.ok()">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="payee">Payee</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="payee" placeholder="Enter payee"
                    ng-model="vm.txn.payee" required>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="memo">Memo</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="memo" placeholder="Enter memo"
                  ng-enter="" ng-model="vm.txn.memo">
        </div>

        ...
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks pankaj. The ng-submit approach also works, but is there a drawback to it? The docs say that we should use either ng-submit or ng-click, but not both - could this pose a limitation? It seems to me that ng-click provides more granular control.

Comment: @Naresh  nope..`ng-submit` looks more proper way of doing angular way validation..in your case you button is outside the `form` context that why you need to go for `ng-click`..and this also clarify that you are not using `ng-submit` with `ng-click` in same form.in addition you could remove you button `type="submit"` there is no form element wrapping to it that means it will do nothing..did you find any wrong with mine answer?

Comment: Nothing wrong with your answer, Pankaj. It works. I am just trying to evaluate the use of ng-click vs. ng-submit. Note the edited code in my original question - the buttons are now inside the form. With this change I was able to make the ng-click work perfectly.

Comment: but personally think that you should use `ng-submit` no need of ng-click then..only button type should be `submit`

Comment: Thanks. I think that makes sense. I suppose ng-click makes more sense when there are more than one submit actions, e.g. a dialog box that allows you to modify or delete an entity. I upvoted your answer.